# Themeing a .NET site just like an Open-source site

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css, .net

This is more of an "approach" question. I want to run the same .NET code, but I want to have the ability to make drastic changes to the UI -- i.e. multiple sites running the same code but different looks/menus/etc. How is this accomplished with .NET? Saying simply "JQuery.UI" is not going to be helpful because all that really does is give you the ability to look slightly different and I am looking for drastically different.

I believe that using multiple master pages is going to resolve the issue. Is there a way to change the master page via code behind? If so, how is that done?

NOTE: We don't want to utilize MVC

Comment: Although this could lead to a great discussion; that in itself means it is a bit broad.  I would also remove the statement "What tools are there?" because that question alone can have your topic closed since tool recommendations are not allowed on SO.  Cheers

Comment: It's in your title. Themes. And you don't even need those. You could change your entire site in a click by loading up a different master page. I have a webforms/mvc hybrid site that has both a fixed-width (old) theme, and a responsive, totally different, theme running concurrently. Same code-base. Different master page.

Comment: MikeSmithDev...but when you create the .aspx pages you have to tell them what masterpage to bind to so that the directive gets created. How do you change the masterpage on the fly like that?

Comment: Is the content same accross sites? Same code base isn't neccesarily the same. If it is functional code, you could utilise base classes in a seperate project and have you functional pages inherit these.

Comment: @MichaelMahony None of my pages use the masterpage that is declared in the aspx. I set the masterpage file in a `PreInit` in global.ascx.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev can you post an example of how you do that?

Comment: @JonP the content is different. We are able to change databases based on CompanyCode and a lookup for that in web.config.

Comment: Voted down? Seriously? And I suppose by the number of answers I received (1) that everybody just "knows" how to do this right?

Comment: @MichaelMahony I think some people vote down or vote to close (it's a 4 votes out of 5 right now) when there is no code/attempt. In my opinion, your question was fine since you didn't know where to start. I don't think it was too broad as there is a straightforward answer on an approach you can take.

Comment: And it may also be how you ask. Here's another recent "approach" question that was actually voted up and has no close votes: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21117271/1810243.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to make drastic UI changes in ASP.NET is by using different Master Pages for each look. You can change which master page is being used from the code-behind.

There is the example on MSDN for [Working with ASP.NET Master Pages Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.ASPX), but instead I do it in global.asax so it can be applied site-wide:

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page p = this.Context.Handler as Page;
    if (p != null)
    {
        p.PreInit += new EventHandler(page_PreInit);
    }
}

protected void page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page p = this.Context.Handler as Page;
    if (p != null)
    {
        p.Theme = "SomeGreatTheme"; //optional.. I personally don't use them.
        p.MasterPageFile = "~/BestMasterPage.master"; //i.e. that web.config value or DB value.
    }
}
```

Though a caveat, it is a little tricky to design a site that is flexible enough to handle many different CSS and master page sources...