# How can I test performance of my web app at different times of the day using an automated script?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, automation, automated-tests

Basically, I have a web application that uses asp.net mvc 4 framework. I use C# as my backend. At different times of the days, I noticed that the web application lags or is slow but I would like to figure out which times of day and some other information that would be useful in figuring out how to optimize the app. I want to be able to write an automated script that tests the web application at different times of the day and correlate it to the slowness of the application.

I'm pretty new to test automation, so I was wondering where could I start with scripting such things. In particular for asp.net web apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this from a few angles:

**Log Stuff**

Log page rendering times, database access times, and times of anything else that might cause slowness.  Use a logging framework such as [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) that allows you to dial up and down the amount of detail you need in the log.

**Get more detail while manually viewing**

Integrate [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) in your website, and have it turn on when you log in.

**Measure live performance of selected pages**

The fast-start solution is to use one of the many external testing solutions out there.  Google *measure website performance free* for a broad selection.

If you want to build this yourself, and especially if you want to test complex workflows, I have had great success with [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/).  JMeter is designed with the goal of stress testing a benchmarking, not live, environment.  However, you could use it to periodically run tests against your production system as long as the tests do not place so much stress on the system so as to be the cause of the problem.

One advantage of using a hosted solution to measure page performance is that they can measure it from different parts of the world.  In some cases, the network latency can be an important component of overall page performance.

Comment: How does JMeter measure performance from different parts of the world? Are there any good tutorials on JMeter for ASP.NET MVC apps?

Comment: JMeter measures performance from where ever you run it.  If you need to test from around the world, you can use a cloud provider like AWS to spin up temporary instances to run JMeter on in whatever part of the world you like.  Be sure and use the public, not private, IP of your web server if it is at the same cloud provider as the JMeter instances (private IP traffic is routed through the cloud's private network).  May be best to use a different cloud for JMeter because even public IP traffic can be optimized. http://build-failed.blogspot.com/2012/06/load-testing-aspnet-mvc-part-2-jmeter.html